# how to make a series of number jumps based on the numbers of variables

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make row of number jumps, example I have `$a = 1` and `$b = 2`. then I want loop $a and $b and the result is `$a = '1', '5', '9', '13', '17'` and `$b = '2', '6', '10', '14', '18'` . How to make it?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add some context as to me it looks like a generic PHP question, but you also added the `codeigniter` tag which looks like there is more to it than you wrote.

If I understand you correctly, you start with two numbers and want to generate an list (array) for each of those numbers. Reusing `$a` and `$b` for the results might not be a good idea. So I suggest you save the result to a different variable:

```php
// initialize A
$a=1;
$a_result=[];

// initialize B
$b=2;
$b_result=[];

// set the jump size
$jump_size=4;

// loop 5 jumps
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    // add new elements to the result arrays
    $a_result[] = $a + $jump_size * $i;
    $b_result[] = $b + $jump_size * $i;
}

// print the results
print_r($a_result);
print_r($b_result);
```

If you have more than just two numbers to start from, you might want to put those in an array too (as well as the result arrays).

Answer (score 0):

**You can check odd or even number using modulo, and skip next number.**

See below example.

[See Running Example](https://ideone.com/2JQHgA)

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

for($i = $a; $i <= 20; $i++){
    if($i > 1 && $i % 2){
        $i = $i + 2;
    }
    if($i % 2 == 1) {
        echo $i;
    } 
}

echo " b=> ";
for($i = $b; $i <= 20; $i++){
    if($i > 1 && $i % 2){
        $i = $i + 2;
    }
    if($i % 2 == 0) {
        echo $i;
    } 
}
```